Android - Kotlin - Link from screen to external (google doc)
I have a biometric login that I would like to link to a Google Docs, both exist and work, but I'm looking for help to connect the two.
I have the Google Docs shared with a link and the source for the biometric login, which works perfectly.
I'd love some help connecting them, so that when clicking on the success text, it opens my link.
Here is the code of the app that returns the success of the login, and the message on screen:
@Composable
fun TextAuthenticationResult(visibilityState: Boolean) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = visibilityState) {
        Text(
            text = "Authentication success",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
            color = Color("#9ccc65".toColorInt())
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp))
    }
}

Can I have some help, please, adapting this so that on touch, it opens a specific link?
Many thanks, all

Its hard coded, Im happy with basic if it works, just appreciate the help.

Do you mean the link will open in the browser when clicking on this?

Thankyou so much for getting back to me. Yes, Id be more than happy for that. I'll try your answer, thankyou so much!

Thankyou so much @NguyenTienDung, that was perfect. It maybe be such as basic question from me but I appreciate you giving me a solution. Much appreciated, have a great day!

Glad to hear it helped ^^ Have a great day!

Add Modifier.clickable to your Text composable and handle the click event like this:
@Composable
fun TextAuthenticationResult(visibilityState: Boolean) {

    val context = LocalContext.current // Get current context

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = visibilityState) {
        Text(
            text = "Your Google Docs link",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
               .padding(5.dp)
               .clickable {
                    // Intent for opening the link in a browser
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(your_google_docs_link_here))
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                },
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
            color = Color("#9ccc65".toColorInt())
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp))
    }
}

